# Autocall- equity/funding correlation

Tags: equities, correlation

Could someone explain how the price of an autocall changes with equity/funding correlation, please?
I have sometimes heard that the trader who sells an autocall is long equity/funding correlation but I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just think of it in terms of the changing duration of the autocall note. Let's use the example of an up-and-out autocall where the buyer is short a put at maturity.

Also, I interpret "funding" as market equity funding $f$, i.e. $\text{Fwd}(t,T)= S e^{(r-q+f)(T-t)}$.

If the stock price decreases, then the autocall note duration increases (less likely to be called). The issuer therefore becomes more short the forward at maturity. This means the issuer is **longer dividends** and **shorter funding**. The issuer makes a mark-to-market gain if both equities and funding decline together, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'the changing duration of the autocall note'?

Comment: In your equation for the Fwd perhaps you are missing the time to maturity.